# SQL Calculate Standard Deviation for all rows between multiples of 3

Tags: sql, sql-server, statistics, ssms

A Table with:

```
Date | Ticker | %Change | stdev
1/1/19  SPY        2       
1/2/19  SPY        -10
1/3/19  SPY        3
1/4/19  SPY        5
.........
```

Output should write into [stdev] into every row between 1-3, 4-7, 8-11, etc.

Comment: What is a row between 1-3, 4-7, 8-11?  I don't understand what your result set looks like.

Comment: Wouldn't that be between rows 1-3, rows 4-6, rows 7-9, rows 10-12, and so forth?

Comment: I'm not certain that standard deviation between three rows is very meaningful. It's going to range all over the place.

Comment: Hi, I'm aiming for higher number of rows ~18. Just put 3 since it would be the same concept